# Create php arrays of date and time from timestamps

Tags: php, datetime, multidimensional-array

I am working with some timestamps from json, which looks like below.

I need to create 2 dropdown buttons, the first of which will list all available dates (November 3rd, November 4th, November 5th) and the second button will list all available dates, depending on the selected option for the date button.

So I've figured I really need to build two arrays which can be referenced between each other. For this, I figured I could just use the `timestamp` as the array key for each array, but the logic for how to create the arrays is escaping me. I am not sure how to do this because the array value gets overwritten by the last occurrence for the date if I split the current timestamp to use as a key like this:

```
foreach ($dates as $index => $date) {
    $dateKey = date('mdy', strtotime($dates->timestamp));
    $newDatesArray[$dateKey] = array($index => date('mdy', strtotime($date->timestamp)));
}
```

Then virtually the same using date `gi` for the hours/minutes. However, I end up with a mess of an array which appears to only contain the last time for that date.

Is this the best way to handle this given the timestamps and data structure I have at my disposal? If there is a better way, what is it? Thanks in advance!

```
{
    "dates": [
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-03T08:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 8},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-03T11:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 10},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-03T13:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 10},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-03T14:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 8},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-04T08:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 10},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-04T11:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 10},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-04T12:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 10},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-04T16:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 10},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-05T06:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 6},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-05T11:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 8},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-05T15:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 6},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-06T06:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 10},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-06T11:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 8},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-06T16:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 8}
  ]}
```

There are 14 items in this array. So I was hoping I could end up with two arrays that can reference each other, i.e. I could get the index of the $newTimesArray array and then get the date from the $newDatesArray arrays key that would look something like this:

```
$newDatesArray = array([0] => "20201103", [1] => "20201104", [2] => "20201105", [3] => "20201106");
```

```
$newTimesArray = array([0] => array([0] => "08:00:00", [1] => "11:00:00", [2] => "13:00:00", [3] => "14:00:00"), [1] => array([0] => "08:00:00", [1] => "11:00:00", [2] => "12:00:00", [3] => "14:00:00"));
```

Comment: Show us an example of what you actually want as the resulting 2 arrays as its not completely clear from your question

Comment: Please share a `var_dump()` of your current (failing) output array, and your intended output format. Also, judging from the missing parenthesis on the first `strtotime()` line, you are manually copying your code into this question. In the future, please always copy-paste code directly from your editor. Lastly, what do you mean by _Then virtually the same using date gi for the hours/minutes_? Do you want to use the time as well? I'm not seeing you use it in the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
$j = '{
    "dates": [
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-03T08:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 8},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-03T11:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 10},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-03T13:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 10},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-03T14:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 8},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-04T08:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 10},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-04T11:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 10},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-04T12:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 10},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-04T16:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 10},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-05T06:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 6},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-05T11:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 8},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-05T15:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 6},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-06T06:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 10},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-06T11:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 8},
    {"timestamp": "2020-11-06T16:00:00","identifier": 23,"referrer": 8}
  ]}';

$json = json_decode($j);

foreach ($json->dates as $i => $date) {
    $d = date('mdy', strtotime($date->timestamp));
    $newDates[$d] = $d;
    $dateTimes[$d][] = date('H:s',strtotime($date->timestamp));
}
print_r($newDates);
print_r($dateTimes);
```

RESULT

```
$newDates AArray
(
    [110320] => 110320
    [110420] => 110420
    [110520] => 110520
    [110620] => 110620
)
$newTimes Array
(
    [110320] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08:00
            [1] => 11:00
            [2] => 13:00
            [3] => 14:00
        )

    [110420] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08:00
            [1] => 11:00
            [2] => 12:00
            [3] => 16:00
        )

    [110520] => Array
        (
            [0] => 06:00
            [1] => 11:00
            [2] => 15:00
        )

    [110620] => Array
        (
            [0] => 06:00
            [1] => 11:00
            [2] => 16:00
        )
```

**UPDATE**
As per your additional request in the comments....

```
foreach ($json->dates as $i => $date) {
    $d = date('mdy', strtotime($date->timestamp));
    $newDates[$d] = $d;
    
    $obj = new stdClass;
    $obj->time = date('H:s',strtotime($date->timestamp));
    $obj->identifier = $date->identifier;
    $obj->referrer = $date->referrer;
    
    $dateTimes[$d][] = $obj;
}
```

NEW RESULTS

```
Array
(
    [110320] => 110320
    [110420] => 110420
    [110520] => 110520
    [110620] => 110620
)
Array
(
    [110320] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [time] => 08:00
                    [identifier] => 23
                    [referrer] => 8
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [time] => 11:00
                    [identifier] => 23
                    [referrer] => 10
                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [time] => 13:00
                    [identifier] => 23
                    [referrer] => 10
                )
            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [time] => 14:00
                    [identifier] => 23
                    [referrer] => 8
                )
        )
    [110420] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [time] => 08:00
                    [identifier] => 23
                    [referrer] => 10
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [time] => 11:00
                    [identifier] => 23
                    [referrer] => 10
                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [time] => 12:00
                    [identifier] => 23
                    [referrer] => 10
                )
            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [time] => 16:00
                    [identifier] => 23
                    [referrer] => 10
                )
        )
    [110520] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [time] => 06:00
                    [identifier] => 23
                    [referrer] => 6
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [time] => 11:00
                    [identifier] => 23
                    [referrer] => 8
                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [time] => 15:00
                    [identifier] => 23
                    [referrer] => 6
                )
        )
    [110620] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [time] => 06:00
                    [identifier] => 23
                    [referrer] => 10
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [time] => 11:00
                    [identifier] => 23
                    [referrer] => 8
                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [time] => 16:00
                    [identifier] => 23
                    [referrer] => 8
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Wow....you made that look easy! That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Noticed a woops in the code, which I have now fixed

Comment: Great, thanks. I'd like to keep the original keys in the $dateTimes, so that the `referrer` and `identifier` are still available. I tried to change `$dateTimes[$d][] = date('H:s',strtotime($date->timestamp));` to `$dateTimes[$d]['time'] = date('H:s',strtotime($date->timestamp));` but I ended up back in my original problem - only one time value would be printed per day.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now :) I added to the answer

Comment: Hero! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!